# Can multiple RAM modules legitimately have identical serial numbers?

Tags: memory, verification, serial-number

Specifically I'm asking about 4x4GB DDR3 SO-DIMMs that I recently purchased. The manufacturer's code is given as `Ox80AD` (which corresponds to SK Hynix) and the serial number as `0x0C415DC9`.

The Amazon seller I bought the RAM from claims the serial numbers are identical because they are from the same batch.

I have been unable to get help from SK Hynix, nor have I been able to find an authoritative answer on the web.

Comment: Sounds like you purchased from a third-party seller instead of directly from Amazon and/or the manufacture, if you have any doubts, my suggestion would be to just return the item.  I would NOT expect two modules to have the same serial number, they might have sequential numbers, if they are part of a kit.